# PowerShell HelpMessage displayed by default in parameters

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to have PowerShell display the help messages by default when parameters are not specified in the command line without the user having to input "!?" for help?

Should I not use param and do it manualy instead with Read-Host if I want my script to be interactive?

```
param (  
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Enter desired password.")][string]$desired_password,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Please input target hostnames.")][string[]]$target_hosts
)
```

What would be the best approach in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some help text to always be displayed if you do not specify a `[String]` parameter, then yes, you have to write this yourself. Example:

```
param(
  [String] $TestParameter
)

if ( -not $TestParameter ) {
  Write-Host "This is help for -TestParameter."
  while ( -not $TestParameter ) {
    $TestParameter = Read-Host "Enter a value"
  }
}

"Argument for -TestParameter: $TestParameter"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, so if I get this straight, there is no way to override the default message right?

Comment: If you want some help text to always be displayed if you don't specify a parameter, then you can write code to accomplish this yourself, as demonstrated in my example.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, currently it's not possible to make a friendly prompt for a missing parameter without Read-Host.
But this could be done in a more elegant manner than in Bill's answer:

```
param(
  [String] $TestParameter=$(Read-Host -prompt "Enter the test parameter")
)
```

Comment: I used this line in a PS script: `param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $ResourceGroup = $(Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the Resource Group name")
)` but didn't work. PSVersion: 5.1.17134.858. I mean the script worked but it didn't show the 'help' message I wanted and instead it used the default `Supply values for the following parameters:` message. Any hints on how to make this work?

Comment: @FelipeRomero you shouldn't specify `Mandatory=$true` if you want to use `Read-Host`. The `Read-Host` is acting as a substitution for `Mandatory` in this case.